# How to check if a term exists with rules - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-rules

I had a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756860/check-if-term-exists-and-create-a-node-with-rules) combining two questions on this subject...but I think I explained a little bit vague...too much story...so I will ask just one question at a time :)

I would like to know how I can check if a taxonomy term exists with Rules in Drupal 7.
I think I will need to do it with a custom PHP rule together with a native Drupal function (something like check_if_term_exists() ?).

But I cannot seem to find a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Nice and easy:

```
$tid = 5; // The term ID, you can't load by term name as such because multiple terms may have the same name within different (and even within the same) vocabularies.
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

if ($term) {
  // The term exists
}
else {
  // The term doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Hi Clive

Thanks for the fast respons!

One more question I have about your answer: the term is inserted into a taxonomy reference field, so its basically just still a text on submit. Is it correct that it does not have a term id yet? And if it does not have an ID yet...what are my options?

Cheers!
Tim